# Unit Test Usage

Tags: c++, unit-testing

As far as I know, unit tests are used to test if the related function works as expected. I would like to know, is this done by only checking the return value of the function?

Other than that are unit test used in different ways? If so could you please you show how.

Comment: you check whatever you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check anything you like. While for functional languages the return value of the function is the only indicator what the function has done you might need to inspect global state (with precedural languages) or object state (in object oriented languages) as well to determine that your test has passed.

As a very simple (and often not necessary) example:

```
void testSetTextSetsText()
{
  Foo foo();
  foo.setText("bar");
  assertEqual("bar", foo.text());
}
```

You cannot really test `void` methods in another way, actually. *Technically* you're checking the return value of a method (`text()`) again here, but most of the time you want to write tests verifying the state visible to an outside observer so this is good enough.

Comment: Why "often not necessary"? Yes, setting a member is trivial, but in wel designed code most things are trivialities built upon other trivialities. But that would mean you need to test only the nontrivial things. And most bugs hide in some trivialities not done right (like e.g. your memleak and the `.` instead of the `->` access). So this test *is* necessary. Maybe not to check if `setText` really does the right thing, but to be sure it does not get changed accidentally.

Comment: I no longer test trivial getters and setters, code coverage be damned. That's boilerplate code in languages that don't support nicer constructs (e.g. Java and C++ compared to C#). When the setter *does* something else than just setting that value I *definitely* want to test that, sure (e.g. if the contract says »When setting a model a new selection model is created as well«). But just for propagation of an argument into a field? I don't really see the need anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You (can) not only check values but also behaviour. For example the throw of an expected exception or a call to an external service using a [Mock-object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

```
void testMethodThrows()
{
    Foo f;
    AssertThrows([&](){f.bar();});
}

void testSendsEmail
{
    Foo f;
    EmailServiceMock email;
    f.bar(email);
    Assert(email.EmailWasSent());
}
```

Comment: Ah, indeed, I forgot those. Brings back bad memories of needing to test exceptions in JUnit 3 ;-)